# Deterministic build of F# NetStandard2.0 / .NET Core 2.0 on Mono

Tags: .net-core, f#, msbuild, mono, deterministic

Is it possible to achieve a F# .Net Standard 2.0 or .NET Core project's build to be deterministic?

For example, this project

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>FS_Core_2._0</RootNamespace>
        <Deterministic>True</Deterministic>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Library.fs"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

produces new binaries on every build while the same `Deterministic` setting for C# works.

Build happens on mono on OSX.

```
Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.1.3 (2018-08/fdb26b0a445 Wed Mar 20 10:02:02 EDT 2019)
```